# Virtual table created by FILTER() function is not recognizable

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables in my PowerBI Model, 'Players' and 'PlayerAttributes', which are connected by 'player_id' column.

I'm trying to create a measure that will be showing a maximum of total stats (which is a metric created by summing all stats values for every player) from a group of players which position is the same as the position of the currently chosen player.

The created measure looks like this:

```
MaxTotalAttributesPosition = 
VAR SamePosition = FILTER(Players, Players[position] = SELECTEDVALUE(Players[position]))

VAR Filtered = FILTER(PlayerAttributes, PlayerAttributes[player_id] = SamePosition[player_id])

VAR Data = SUMMARIZE(
        ALL(Filtered),
        PlayerAttributes[player_id],
        "AttrSum", SUM(PlayerAttributes[Value])
         )
         
RETURN
CALCULATE(MAXX(Data, [AttrSum]))
```

When trying to evaluate this measure i get the error: *"Cannot find table 'SamePosition'."* I suspect that the way I'm using the Filter() function is not correct, because the interpreter cannot recognize tables created via Filter function.